# Postgres - insert with manytoone relation

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert, sql-insert

I am using **Postgres 14** and writing an *sql* query so I can insert a new row into `tag` table:

| id | team_id | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 4 | London On |

As simple as:

```
 INSERT INTO tag (team_id, name) SELECT :teamId, :name;

    $stmt->bindValue("teamId", 4, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindValue("name", 'London On', PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue("teamMemberId", 428, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

In `tag` table I have `ManyToOne` relation with `team_member_tag` table that should look like:

| id | team_member_id | tag_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 314 | 428 | 2 |

I want to implement `INSERT` of the data into `team_member_tag` table when doing an insert into `tag` table.. I have all params needed as I wrote in an example.

Tried:

```
$stmt = $this->getConnection()->prepare(
        '
            INSERT INTO tag
            (
             team_id,
             name
            ) VALUES (
               :teamId,
               :name,
            ) RETURNING tag.id
            '
    );

    $stmt->executeQuery();

    $stmt2 = $this->getConnection()->prepare('
    INSERT INTO team_member_tag (team_member_id, tag_id)
        VALUES
        ( :workspaceMemberId,
          (select id from tag)
        )
    ');

    $stmt2->bindValue('workspaceMemberId', $workspaceMemberId);
    $stmt2->executeQuery();
```

And now the error:

> Cardinality violation: 7 ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Can you please help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect syntax:

```
INSERT INTO team_member_tag (team_member_id, tag_id)
VALUES
( :workspaceMemberId,
  (select id from tag)
)
```

Because `select id from tag` may be gets many records but inside values must be only one value.

For inserting multiple rows to table you can use this syntax, for example:

```
INSERT INTO team_member_tag (tag_id)
select id from tag
```

But if you need insert into `team_member_tag` table only inserted tag values you can use this syntax:

```
with t1 as (
    INSERT INTO tag (team_id, name) VALUES (:teamId,:name)
    RETURNING id
) 
insert into team_member_tag (team_member_id, tag_id)
select 10, t1.id from t1
```

10 - sample value for `team_member_id` field.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your example did it. I was struggling with syntax for quite some time.. @RaminFaracov